# Multi-line template string with no newline characters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, template-literals, template-strings

I have this single line of code:

```
 console.log(`now running each hook with name '${chalk.yellow(aBeforeOrAfterEach.desc)}', for test case with name '${chalk.magenta(test.desc)}'.`);
```

the problem is I have to put it on multiple lines in my IDE, for it to fit (I go with 100 columns). When I put a template string on multiple lines, the template string interprets it as newline characters, which is not what I want.

So my question is - how can I have multiple lines of template string code without having it be logged with new line characters?

Comment: Concatenation??

Comment: `\`foo\`` + `\`bar\`` works, but I think the backslash solution is neat

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use a backslash - `\` - at the end of every line to avoid an insertion of `\n`

```js
 console.log(`\
 now running each hook with name \
'${'foo'}', for test case with name '${'bar'}' \
.`);
```

Another option should be to use `.split("\n").join('')` which will replace all newlines with a empty string

Comment: this technique didn't work as well as I thought it would, after every \ it seems to add the literal whitespace that's in the template string to the output, kinda weird, I will keep trying it.

Comment: can you supply an example?

Comment: Yeah the backslash seems to take any whitespace from indentation as a literal whitespace inside the string. The only solution I see is to ignore the indentation rules in a separate file where you import the string in, but this obviously isn't the cleanest solution.

Comment: @Nick Try [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70208667/99717).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
const foo = "foo"
const bar = "bar"

console.log(`now running each hook with name ` +
    `'${foo}', for test case with name '${bar}'` +
    `.`);
```

This should **not** preserve **any** whitespace, including the indents.

Answer (score 0):

At this point I guess this is as best as we can do:

```
const trim = (v: string) => String(v || '').trim()
const mapTemplateStrings = (v :Array<string>) => v.map(trim).join(' ');

console.log(mapTemplateStrings([
    `first line ${'one'}`,
    `second line ${'second'} and yada`,
    `bidding war ${'three'}`
]));
```